# Including multiple bibliographies with the same entries

Tags: bibtex

I would like to include multiple bibliographies in the same document. However, there is an overlap in the entries, that means in bibliography 1 I have partially the same entries as in bibliography 2. Tex seems to mix up the order in this case.

I pre-compile each chapter and copy the content of the .bbl file where the library goes.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,onecolumn,11pt,a4paper]{book}
\begin{document}

\chapter{1}
Text with citation\cite{item1,item2}.

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{item1}
J. Doe, {\em title}, Journal (2020).

\bibitem{item2}
M. Mouse, {\em title2}, Journal2 (2020).
\end{thebibliography}

\chapter{2}
Text has citations also from chapter 1, but in a different order\cite{item2,item1}.

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{item2}
M. Mouse, {\em title2}, Journal2 (2020).

\bibitem{item1}
J. Doe, {\em title}, Journal (2020).
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Compiling (pdflatex) yields

Chapter 1
1
Text with citation[2, 1].

Chapter 2
2
Text has citations also from chapter 1, but in a dierent order[1, 2].

I would like to have in chapter 1: Text with citation[1, 2].

Comment: There is the `multibib` package for that.

Comment: You mean something like `\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}`? Unfortunately that does not do anything. Do you know if I have to include the bibliographies using a `\bibliographry{}` command and then calling bibtex on each for multilib to work properly? Or can it be used with the library defined as above?

Comment: This package allows you to have multiple bibliographies, each of which you need to process/generate with bibtex. You can then have commands like `\citeone` and so on that refer to an entry of the respective bibliography. I guess it will be best if you look for examples on this site, I may completely misunderstand the question.